# Getting "No Wifi adaptor found" for ubuntu 18.04 in DELL precision

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I use DELL Precision 3541.

After rebooting my laptop, I am getting "No Wifi adaptor found". So I tried few solutions mentioned in stackoverflow. But when I hit `sudo lshw -C network`

I am getting this in response

```
      description: Network controller
      product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 14.3
      bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
      version: 10
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
      configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
      resources: irq:16 memory:ed43c000-ed43ffff
 *-network:1
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 1f.6
      bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
      logical name: eno2
      version: 10
      serial: 34:48:ed:03:b3:22
      capacity: 1Gbit/s
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
      resources: irq:172 memory:ed400000-ed41ffff
```

There is no logical name for my wifi adaptor.

Is there any way I can enable the wifi adaptor on my laptop?

Comment: You will have better luck at askubuntu.com with this question, since it is not a programming question

Comment: This question is more suitable for [ubuntu.se], as it is not programming related. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: Thanks! I will try there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something random. Dont know how it worked for me. Just followed the steps.

1.Restarted my Laptop.

2.Entered BOIS setup (F12).

3.Then inside the wireless section, I completely disabled WLAN.

4.When it booted up successfully, Restarted Laptop again.

5.Entered BOIS setup and enabled the WLAN.

Finally, when the laptop turned on, everything was working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I installed ubuntu 20.04 and wifi was not working, message was same as "No wifi adaptor found".

I had onboard wifi adaptor.

Using command sudo lshw -C network, I got

```html
*-network
  description: Wireless interface
  product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
 vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I knew that my wifi adaptor is of Intel® and now I found that Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz is the actual adaptor.

After doing hours of googling, I went on intel official site and found this link [Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html)

I found that my adaptor was listed there under **Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz**

I downloaded **iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz** and extracted it under the directory **/lib/firmware** as mentioned on intel site.

wooooooooooooo, ubuntu was able to detect the adaptor and my wifi connections were listed under wifi settings.

You may need to restart the system, though in my case it worked as soon as I extracted the files in **/lib/firmware**.